# Why in SAS data step where works but not if

Tags: sas

**Working code:**

```
data t2;

 set t1; 
 
 where a like "%SR";

run;
```

**Code errored:**

```
data t2;

 set t1; 

 if a like "%SR";

run;
```

Error message:
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.

It complained about 'like'

Any ideal?

Comment: You can not ike the LIke Operator in an If Statement. Do you want an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIKE is not an operator that SAS code understands. The only reason it works in WHERE is because WHERE statement supports SQL syntax such as LIKE and BETWEEN to make it easier to push the WHERE condition into a remote database.

Use some other way to test if the last two letters are SR.  Here are two methods.

```
if 'SR' = substrn(a,length(a)-1);
if 'RS' =: left(reverse((a)) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked beautifully. I did not realize that Like only workes in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The most similar solution is to use [prxmatch](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/n0bj9p4401w3n9n1gmv6tfshit9m.htm):

```
data t2;
 set t1; 
 if prxmatch("/.*SR/ios",a);
run;
```

Note that this is much slower than WHERE with LIKE, and Tom's solutions are faster if there's a reasonable way to do them (as there is in the example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i needed to find the records where a ends with 'SR' so this would not work. but this would be good for searching if a substring exists, similar to index function.

Comment: This actually should work fine for that (though you may need to allow for space padding).  I'd still use other methods though if you can, as they're probably more efficient

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE` operator is not understood by the DATA Step `IF` statement.

`LIKE` **is** available to DATA Step in the `WHERE` statement, the `WHERE=` data set option, or PROC SQL `WHERE` clause.

```
data have;
  input text $CHAR20.;
  datalines;
ABCEFG
YESSR
Mark JR
Mark SR
;

data want;
  set have;
  where text like '%SR';  /* where statement */
run;

data want;
  set have(where=(text like '%SR')); /* where= option */
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select text from have
  where text like '%SR'     /* where clause */
  ;
```